# get List<SomeClass> after .GroupBy()

Tags: c#, select, group-by

Can someone explain me how i can use `GroupBy` with `Select` to get from this:

```
public class BadClass{
    public int id; //can be grouped by id
    public string name; //identical for the same Id
    public bool flag; //identical for the same Id
    public int bId;
    public string bName;
    public int cId;
    public string cName;
}
```

This one: `List <A>` where:

```
public class A {
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public bool flag;
    public List<B> bList;
}

public class B {
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public C c;
}

public class C {
    public int id;
    public int name;
}
```

I make example of data in BadClass:

```
List<BadClass> badClass = new List<BadClass>() {
    new BadClass(){ id = 1, name = "A1", flag = true, bId = 1, bName = "B1", cId = 1, cName = "C1" },
    new BadClass(){ id = 1, name = "A1", flag = true, bId = 2, bName = "B2", cId = 3, cName = "C2" },
    new BadClass(){ id = 1, name = "A1", flag = true, bId = 3, bName = "B3", cId = 1, cName = "C1" },
    new BadClass(){ id = 2, name = "A2", flag = false, bId = 4, bName = "B4", cId = 2, cName = "C2" },
    new BadClass(){ id = 2, name = "A2", flag = false, bId = 5, bName = "B5", cId = 3, cName = "C3" }
};

/*
+----+------+-------+-----+-------+-----+-------+
| id | name |  flag | bId | bName | cId | cName |
+----+------+-------+-----+-------+-----+-------+
|  1 |  A1  |  true |  1  |   B1  |  1  |   C1  |
+----+------+-------+-----+-------+-----+-------+
|  1 |  A1  |  true |  2  |   B2  |  1  |   C1  |
+----+------+-------+-----+-------+-----+-------+
|  1 |  A1  |  true |  3  |   B3  |  3  |   C3  |
+----+------+-------+-----+-------+-----+-------+
|  2 |  A2  | false |  4  |   B4  |  2  |   C2  |
+----+------+-------+-----+-------+-----+-------+
|  2 |  A2  | false |  5  |   B5  |  3  |   C3  |
+----+------+-------+-----+-------+-----+-------+
*/
```

I try to make something like that:

```
var result = badClass.GroupBy(x => x.id).Select(x => x. ???? ) ???? =(
```

but don't know how to make it right.

**UPDATE:**

```
var result = badClass
    .GroupBy(x => x.id)
    .Select(x => new A {
        id = x.Key,
        name = x.First().name,
        flag = x.First().flag,
        bList = x.ToList()
    });
```

here is error in `bList = x.ToList();` I need to change names `bId` to `id` e.t.c.

**ANSWER:**

```
var result = badClass
        .GroupBy(x => x.id)
        .Select(x => new A
        {
            id = x.Key,
            name = x.First().name,
            flag = x.First().flag,
            bList = badClass.Where(y => y.id == x.Key).Select(y =>
                new B { id = y.bId, name = y.bName, c = new C { id = y.cId, name = y.cName } }).ToList()
        });
```

Comment: `.Select(x => x.Key)` should contain your grouped on, while `.Select(x => x.ToList())` should contain your items within that group. Combine what you need.

Comment: `var result = badClass.GroupBy(x => x.id).Select(x => new A { id = x.Key, name = x.First().name, flag = x.First().flag, bList = x.ToList()});`
here is error in `bList = x.ToList();` I need to change names `bId` to `id` e.t.c.

Comment: @Caramiriel  
i need to rename bId, bName, cId, cName, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = badClass
        .GroupBy(x => x.id)
        .Select(x => new A
        {
            id = x.Key,
            name = x.First().name,
            flag = x.First().flag,
            bList = badClass.Where(y => y.id == x.Key).Select(y =>
                new B { id = y.bId, name = y.bName, c = new C { id = y.cId, name = y.cName } }).ToList()
        });
```

This should get you what you want

But to be honest I would prefer a `foreach` loop + `Dictionary` for readability.

Comment: Cool, thanks! That is that i need! Why you preder `foreach` loop + `Dictionary`? Is it work faster?

Comment: @DenisRoss for small dataset the difference is negligible. For large dataset Dictionary is faster. But the main reason is because of the readability there. foreach is easier for other ppl to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a .Select and ToList which will has all the items you need

```
var result = badClass.GroupBy(x => x.id).Select(x => x.ToList());
```

Comment: i need to convet it to `List<A>` with rename `bId`,`bName`,`cId`,`cName`

Comment: i need to rename bId, bName, cId, cName, but don't know how.